# WordPress AJAX "POST" response only works from functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to create a stand alone WordPress Ajax plugin.

The code works but only if I put the PHP code to process the Ajax POST request in my WordPress theme's functions.php file.

When I put the PHP code to process the request in a separate file within my plugin folder instead of functions.php, I get POST response 0.

I've been struggling with this for days now, any help would be appreciated.

**Main Plugin .PHP**

```
<?php
/**
*Plugin Name: poc-invoice-ajax
*Description: Custom POC Invoicing
*Author: A-POC
**/

if (! defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_poc_invoice_send','poc_invoice_send');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_poc_invoice_send','poc_invoice_send');
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_poc_assets');
function load_poc_assets(){

    global $template;

    if ( basename( $template ) === 'poc.php' ) {

        
        wp_enqueue_script('ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/poc-invoice.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ));
        wp_enqueue_script('poc-process', plugins_url( '/process/index.php', __FILE__ ));
        wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'poc_invoice_js_objects', array(
            'security' => wp_create_nonce( 'poc_invoice_nonce' ),
            'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )
        ));
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jspdf', $src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js');
}  
}
?>
```

**Javascript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("#form1").submit(function(){
      event.preventDefault();
      var form_data = jQuery(this).serialize();
  
      var formdata = new FormData;
      formdata.append('enquiry', form_data)

      jQuery.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: poc_invoice_js_objects.ajax_url,
        data: {
                action: 'poc_invoice_send',
                //security: poc_invoice_js_objects.security,
                data: form_data
              },
    
        success: function(data){
            
          console.log(data)
        }

      });
   });
});
```

**PHP code to process ajax request:**
[If this code is in functions.php the ajax POST will send the correct response.]

```
<?php
$path = preg_replace('/wp-content.*$/','',__DIR__);
require_once($path."wp-load.php");

add_action('wp_ajax_poc_invoice_send','poc_invoice_send');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_poc_invoice_send','poc_invoice_send');
function poc_invoice_send() {
    echo "test";
    wp_die();
    }
?>
```

**Plugin Folder Structure:**

Plugin Folder:

- Main Plugin.php
- js (folder)

  - plugin.js
- process (folder)

  - index.php (standalone PHP code to process the Ajax request )

Comment: What is the structure of your plugin folder - is this php part of another plugin of yours or is it stand-alone?

Comment: Apologies, I've edited the post to include the folder structure. The PHP code is in it's own file, within a sub folder of the plugin folder.